# Nested Mouse Events won't work

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am creating a video player in AS3.  The different sections of it are divided into classes.  When the mouse rolls over the video, the tool bar comes up.  The toolbar itself is in a seperate class.  My issue is that the ROLL_OVER's for each button on the toolbar won't function when the mouse rolls over them.

Tool Bar Constructor

```
//Constructor
        public function ToolBar()
        {
            populateHitZones();
            drawSelf();


            for (var j:int = 0; j < highLights.length; j++)
            {
                highLights[j].addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, over, false, 0);
                highLights[j].addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, out, false, 0);
            }

        }
        //End Constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

use MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER and MoouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT instead.  MOUSE_OVER event has the bubbles property set to true and the ROLL_OVER to false.

Comment: I've tried both and they don't seem to work.  I know useCapture by default is set to false so their shouldn't be an issue.  Is their any other property that I could be forgetting to enable bubbling?  Or are their any known issues with events placed on child objects of a Movie Clip that already has an event?